# How to set up a proper JUnit environment for Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I find it a pain to set-up JUnit environment for Spring.

Partly because all the configuration file are all in a single XML.

therefore when I wish to test a hibernate entity, the entire load of other entities will be loaded.

Which is very inefficient.

May i know is there any recommend way for setting up JUnit environment for Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create your custom  `testApplicationContext.xml`  which has only the entities and you need.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:resources/spring/testApplicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)
public class MyTest extends TestCase {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is

> all the configuration file are all in a single XML

you'd better split your configuration into several modules, for example one for hibernate/datasource, one for services, and one for controllers, then you can load different modules for different tests